# How can you resize an element that is vertically adjacent to another, that shows/hides content as it resizes?

Tags: css

I'm trying to find a way to make an element resizable so that it will simultaneously reveal more of the element's content as the height increases while covering the content of the other element that it is taking space from.

An example of this is of Gmail's left sidebar, these two images show before and after the resize drag: [Sidebar Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTUMC.png) - [Sidebar After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qqz1.png)

I was thinking it could be done with the CSS resize property, but while the lower element can be resized downwards, it won't resize upwards taking space from the above element, and the resize grabber also seems to be difficult to change its position from the bottom right to the top.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `resize` property together with a flex setting that causes the other element to occupy the rest of the space.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 80vh;
  margin:1em;
}

.container>div {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow: auto;
}

.top {
  resize: vertical;
  height: 50%;
}

.bottom {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga repellat laborum maxime ipsam sed quisquam, numquam eligendi doloribus non nisi unde vero deleniti velit dolore nesciunt error, sapiente provident at sint sunt! Cumque nostrum, placeat nisi,
    minima, maiores molestiae quas praesentium mollitia hic natus suscipit nemo accusantium, beatae itaque rem aut omnis? Quisquam, natus dicta eveniet! Voluptates repellat, assumenda fugit. At, culpa quos nulla. Dolorem et modi quisquam velit quaerat
    aspernatur iste natus eum magnam vero, id eius expedita quo placeat maiores enim quas iusto amet dolor ullam aperiam sequi laboriosam. Omnis voluptas, a exercitationem cum quidem quaerat ullam deleniti.
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet a magni culpa quidem in et facilis, ducimus voluptate explicabo saepe repellat, eius sequi molestias voluptatum! Maiores animi quasi quia nisi, pariatur id aperiam! Veritatis error molestias
    minima modi suscipit ipsam eius sed perspiciatis est nobis illo, incidunt itaque harum, distinctio?
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! I thought the resize was on the bottom element but it seems it can look and work the same even if it's on the top element instead. However, I'm still unsure how to go about re-positioning the resize grabber so that it is in the centre bottom of the div, I tried using the ::-webkit-resizer selector but not having much luck!